# Java. Find the lengths of strings in an array list for which those string lengths occur the most

Tags: java, arrays, spring, sorting, arraylist

For example, say I have the following array after splitting it.

[Hello, world, what, a, fine, day, it, is, the, date, is, 01/10/2020]

10 characters - 01/10/2020 (I know it's a date field, in this instance pretend its a string)

5 characters - Hello, world

4 characters - what, fine, date

3 characters - day, the

2 characters - it, is, is

1 characters - a

So in this instance, 4 characters and 2 characters are what I'm hoping to get, as they both share the highest lengths within the list array.

Help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because ["Questions asking for homework help must include a **summary of the work you've done so far** to solve the problem, and a **description of the difficulty you are having** solving it."](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Take a look at a Hashmap with <String, Integer> for all the String counts. Or HashMap<Integer,Integer>, where you'd use the length of string as key and count in the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of Java Stream Library's `groupingBy` collector

```
String[] arr = new String[]{
        "Hello",
        "world",
        "what",
        "a",
        "fine",
        "day",
        "it",
        "is",
        "the",
        "date",
        "is",
        "01/10/2020"
};

List<Integer> maxRepeatingSizes =
    Arrays.stream(arr)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                String::length,
                Collectors.counting()
            )).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                            Map.Entry::getValue,
                            Collectors.mapping(
                                Map.Entry::getKey,
                                Collectors.toList()
                            )
                    )
            ).entrySet()
            .stream()
            .max(
                    Map.Entry.comparingByKey()
            ).get()
            .getValue();
```

First, the array is grouped using the length of the string as key, and count as value.
Next, the Map of Length and Count is inverted to obtain a Map of Count and List of Lengths for that count.
Then, the maximum repeated values are taken by sorting the Map according to the key.